# unexpected kernel mode trap after publishing a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

For a number of years I have been programming software that uses an accdb database.
Since several people are currently using this program (in the same network, but it also works offline), I had previously written an extra program for updates.
up to this point everything is fine.

But now I wanted to give the program to my work colleagues as a permanently installed tool.
The "publishing" from visual studio also allows you to check existing updates. So exactly my thing what I needed.

Now to the problem: if I publish the project locally on my pc, I can easily execute the setup.exe.
If I publish the project on our NAS, everyone can start / see setup.exe, except me.
At the exact moment when the exe icon should be loaded, I get a bluescreen with the above mentioned message.
In the event view of windows 10, the error code 0x000007f is mentioned.
According to M$, a coprocessor is being addressed that is not available and therefore the error is generated. But I'm not sure because the other pc's don't have the error.

os: win 10 version 2004

Edit: this happens with vs 2017 and 2019 and also when other pc's publish the project with vs. but only my pc is affected.

Translated with google, my english isn't that good enough -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hardware/OS fault and can't have much to do with the software package you've published.

Nothing in regular user-developed software should be able to cause a blue screen stop, but something in what you've written does hit your box in the wrong way. Maybe an antivirus package gets confused?

Nirsoft has a tool that can help you see what software is being involved in a fault: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

Comment: there is eset installed. i will check it, when eset is disabled.

Comment: thanks, that helped, eset was the problem. now i remember when eset hasn't showed the dvd-drive on a laptop, because it blocked the driver... such a shitty program -.-

Comment: Glad I could help :) As an aside, since you're using Windows 10, the built-in Windows Antimalware plus some common sense is enough for most folks.

Comment: i know, but my boss had it installed by a computer company that maintains the server and the inventory management program